# Не передается значение из POST запроса в переменную

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, javascript-faq

Есть проблема. Делаю POST запрос для медиафайлов. При получении ответа от сервера, передаю путь и тип файла в переменные. Приходит ответ, но значения не передаются. Что делать, помогите плиз?

```
formEl.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
const formData = new FormData(evt.currentTarget);
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', `${apiUrl}/media`);
    xhr.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
        const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        pathFile = data.path;
        typeFile = data.type;
    }),
        xhr.send(formData);

    const file = pathFile; //переменные для получения значения из запроса
    const type = typeFile; //переменные для получения значения из запроса

    let std = {
        id: 0,
        author,
        text,
        type,
        file,
    };
});
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: А в моем случае, как его (функцию) использовать? Не подскажете? Просто я в этом направлении, пока новичок )

Comment: У вас асинхронная функция, в вашем случае код выполнил строку, не дождался её завершения и пошел к другой, соответственно и переменная пустая. Воспользуйтесь async/await или из гайда выше.

Comment: @MoloF, да, спасибо, я понял это, но не знаю как это реализовать? Покажете на моем примере?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const apiUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb';

form.onsubmit = async (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();

 let result = {};
 
 const fetchOptions = { method: 'GET' };
 try {
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl, fetchOptions);
  if (response.status !== 200)
   throw new Error('Bad status code');
   
  result = await response.json();
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  return;
 }
 
 console.log('results' in result && result.results);
};
```

```html
<form id="form">
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```